# Python Boto3 List Instances in a Dataframe Windowed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to list my EC2 instances in a table with Boto3.

```
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
instance_count = sum(1 for _ in instances.all())
RunningInstances = []
for instance in instances:
    id = instance.id
    name = self.get_name_tag(instance)
    type = instance.instance_type
    mylist = {"name":name,"id":id,"type":type}
    RunningInstances.append(mylist.copy())
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(RunningInstances)
print(table)
```

This creates a table - which is great! My problem is that the columns overflow to another row even when the columns can fit in the current window:

```
                 id                                           name  \
0            i-56b243ge                                       My Really Long Name for my Instance
1            i-89b789ga                                       My 2nd Really Long Name for my Instance

                 type
0            t2-micro
1            t2-small
```

I just learned that Pandas exists today so I haven't quite mastered styling. Keep in mind that the name column header is to the right of the name values - I just can't put it there because of Stack's formatting. How can I get all of a Dataframe/table into a single view?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Pandas, you'll love the way it performs operations on dataframes without expecting you to iterate over the values. I've changed your parsing a bit, to demonstrate some of it's abilities!

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
client=boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instances()
df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(
    pd.DataFrame(
        pd.DataFrame(
            response['Reservations']
        )\
        .apply(lambda r: r.str[0])\. # Get only the first element of the list
        .Instances\
        .values
        )[0]
    )[['ImageId','InstanceType','Tags']]
df['Name']=df.Tags.apply(lambda r: r[0]['Value']) # Get the name from the tags dict
df.drop(['Tags'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

Will give you:

```
    ImageId InstanceType Name
0   ami-123 t2.2xlarge   name1
1   ami-234 t2.large     name2
2   ami-345 m5.12xlarge  name3
```